# jQuery: how to retrieve element by concatenated ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating and generating their id's to be something like `hidden1234`.

In the below Javascript code, `var hid` is retrieved properly by `document.getElementById`. But the jQuery line below has a syntax error. How can I retrieve this element by Id using jQuery?

```
var hid = document.getElementById('hidden'+id);
var hidden = $("#'hidden'+id");
```

Comment: To select an id use `#`, `.` is for classes. Then it should be `$("#hidden" + id)`.

Comment: oops, same syntax error though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a simple typo:

```
var hidden = $('#hidden'+id);
```

You want to select an element with the id `'hidden' + id`. The according CSS / jQuery selector therefore looks like `'#hidden' + id`.